# Unable to load android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I have implemented **android Google maps V2** in my application and its working fine on most of the devices(**Galaxy Ace Plus, Galaxy 7inch Tab, Sony Xperia Z**) i tested. But it's not working on **HTC Desire**. i have cross verified the **Google play services** also installed in that device. i goggled a lot to find a solution. below is my implementation.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();        
}
}
```

below is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/the_map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
map:cameraTilt="45"
map:cameraZoom="2" />
```

and here is manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.raj.googlemapsv2test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="com.raj.googlemapsv2test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.raj.googlemapsv2test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDD6bvUVkTk2UzOLpojdeBtlh5xBYDhy6E" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.raj.googlemapsv2test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

when i check the logs its showing the following error lines.

```
 Could not find class 'maps.i.k', referenced from method maps.z.ag.a
 Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
 Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
```

and finally with a small doubt i updated the **goggle maps app** in the device and after that it's working.
So I wants to show an alert to the user for update when this kind of issue is found with any of the devices. But unable to know how to check this. So Can any one suggest some way to find whether the **goggle maps app** and **android goggle play services** in the device are of the supportive version to this **android Goggle Maps V2** or not.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue on an HTC Desire, except mine says "Could not find class 'maps.af.k', referenced from method maps.ag.an.a". It also says that it is "unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/w; (734)". Updating the Google Maps app like you said did not fix the issue, I still cannot see a map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this code to your onResume method. It checks if the user has an updated version of the Google Play Services, and if he does not, a popup redirecting him to the Google Play is shown.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS && GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)){
        Dialog d = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0, new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //As my application does a heavy use of maps, if the user cancels the dialog, I just finish the FragmentActivity
                MainFragmentActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        d.show();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (supportMapFragment == null) {
        supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, supportMapFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

at this time google play services are not initialize so get map and add what ever you want to it in onResume() or onStart()

```
   @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (gMap == null) {
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}
```

after adding this u need to implement OnMapReadyCallback. and do what ever operations u like to do with map.